# Rails: Parse XML Document with Same Path Names

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I have a document with paths with the same name. For example:

```
 xml_doc = Nokogiri::XML(response.body)
  photo = xml_doc.xpath('person').xpath('photos').xpath('photo').xpath('url').inner_text
```

It returns several photos (because all photos have the same path names).

How can I say to Nokogiri to just return the first one? Or one that has a string inside?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
xml_doc.xpath('person/photos/photo/url')[0]
```

or

```
xml_doc.xpath('person/photos/photo/url[not(text()="")]')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `at_css` method:

```
 xml_doc.at_css('person photos photo url')
 # just css will return all, just like xpath
 xml_doc.css('person photos photo url')
```

Personally, I find `css` and `at_css` much more intuitive and easier to use.